# sqlsrv driver showing up in phpmyinfo but connection still fails

Tags: php, sql-server, driver

I have successfully loaded the sqlsrv_pdo_54 driver that is right for me with ts and vc9 and php 5.4 which I am running, and it shows up in phpmyinfo. I have downloaded the windows native client, switched my port to 8080, and have wamp 32 bit running on my computer. However, whenever I run the following script

```
<?php
require_once 'trunk\global.inc.php';

              $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
               if($conn === false)
              {
                  die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
              }
?>
```

I get the following error message:

```
 Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\wamp\www\test.php on line 11
```

Apparently the function is still undefined. Why is this happening when the driver has been loaded? I tried restarting my server and it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sqlsrv_pdo doesn't use the standard `sqlsrv_*` functions.  It uses PDO.  Try changing your code to use PDO.

```
<?php
require_once 'trunk\global.inc.php';

              $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=MY_SERVER;Database=MY_DATABASE", MY_USERNAME, MY_PASSWORD);
               if($conn === false)
              {
                  die('Unable to connect to DB');
              }
?>
```

Comment: `sqlsrv_errors` still won"t work though, you should use the PDO equivalent of it

Comment: @BotondBalázs Yes, sorry.  I forgot to replace that portion of the code before submitting.